# Android -(Thread) app will hang when I run a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have 3 activities in my android Application. In the first activity, on the click of a bluetooth device from the list of paired devices, I'm starting a service to keep the bluetooth connection visible to all the actives. In the service class I'm reading data continuously from the bluetooth device and I'm binding the second activity to the service class to read the data received.

I'm not able to get the instance of the binder outside the `onServiceConnected()` method of service connection method. So I'm calling a user-defined thread from `onServiceConnected()` method. In this way I'm getting values continuously from the service class. But the app will not respond after few seconds of successful execution.

It is blocking the main thread I think. But I'm not getting where I need to modify my code. The code below is my second Activity(MainActivity). "bluetoothManager" is my service class. I need to do a similar task in third activity also.

I'm not getting whether the problem is with binding or the thread. I need to call the thread outside of the Service connection class. If I do so, I'll get a null pointer exception. So I'm calling the thread from `onServiceConnected()` function where the binder object is not null. I have to use the boolean `mIsBound` for the while loop. But now it will be always true. Please help me. I'm new to android.

```
bluetoothManager.class
public class bluetoothManager extends Service{
final int handlerState = 0; // used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
public ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
static Handler bluetoothIn;

int bp;
String sensor0,sensor1; 
static Handler  mHandler;
// SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
  IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


 public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
   bluetoothManager getService() {        
        return bluetoothManager.this;           
    }
}




    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       /// Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // flag="created";
    }
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        // creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }
    public String getBPM(){  
            return sensor1;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       final String address=intent.getStringExtra("address");          
        final int currentId = startId;

        if(address!=null)
        {
            btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);            
        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);               
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check
        // device is connected
        // If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and
        // finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");
        }
        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == handlerState) { // if message is what we want
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj; // msg.arg1 = bytes
                                                    // from connect
                                                    // thread
            recDataString.append(readMessage); // keep appending to
                                                // string until ~
            int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~"); // determine
                                                                // the
                                                                // end-of-line
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) { // make sure there data before ~
                String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0,
                        endOfLineIndex); // extract string
                //txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                /*int dataLength = */dataInPrint.length(); // get length of
                                                        // data received
                /*txtStringLength.setText("String Length = "
                        + String.valueOf(dataLength));*/

                if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#') // if it starts with
                                                    // # we know it is
                                                    // what we are
                                                    // looking for
                {

                     sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1,3);
                     // get
                     sensor1=sensor0;

                    Log.d("bpm", sensor0);
                                        }
                recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length()); // clear
                                                                    // all
                                                                    // string
                                                                    // data
                // strIncom =" ";
                dataInPrint = " ";
            }
        }
    }

};

 // get Bluetooth
                                                    // adapter


        return currentId;
    }
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        // creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                // Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); // read bytes from input
                                                        // buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1,
                            readMessage).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

            // write method
            public void write(String input) {
                byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes(); // converts entered String into
                                                        // bytes
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer); // write bytes over BT connection
                                                    // via outstream
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // if you cannot write, close the application
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      

                }
            }


    }
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v("myservice", "in onRebind");
    super.onRebind(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v("myapp", "in onUnbind");
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("myservice", "in onDestroy");

    }   


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServiceConnection mConnection;
    TextView  sensorView0;

    boolean mIsBound;
    bluetoothManager bm;
    private Handler bpmHandler;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection;

    final int handlerState = 0; // used to identify handler message

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bpm);
        bpmHandler=new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String s=(String)msg.obj;
                    sensorView0.setText("BPM="+s);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mConnection= new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mIsBound = false;
                bm=null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                LocalBinder myBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
                mIsBound = true;
                bm=myBinder.getService();
                mConnectedService=new ConnectedService(mIsBound);
                mConnectedService.start();
            }
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bluetoothManager.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
    private class ConnectedService extends Thread {
        final boolean bound;

        public  ConnectedService(boolean mIsBound){

            bound =mIsBound;

        }
        public void run() {
            String s;
            while (bound) {
                s= bm.getBPM();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what =handlerState ;
                msg.obj=s;  MainActivity.this.bpmHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ANR happening? What do u see in the logcat?

Comment: Nothing will be displayed in the logcat.when we press the back button,it wont work .if we press more than once ANR  will occur.-@7383

Comment: It is better to post Bluetooth manager code to understand the issue

Comment: Please check the BluetoothManager  class code.I just need to display the string sensor0 in BluetoothManager class in MainActivity continuously Thank you for reading the whole code..@7383

Comment: I feel the connectedservice thread code is causing the issue. Instead of continuously racing grtBPM method, why don't you post the message only when there is a change. You can use local broadcast manager to broadcast the message from service and catch that in activity and update UI accordingly.  The connectedservice thread runs continuously and keep posting the message to handler which is causing load on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much bro.. Done that with localbroadcast manager only.. working fine now..@7383

Comment: Hey I will add my comment as answer please accept n upvote the answer

Comment: Voting is important to improve the reputation, please accept the answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: @7383 I already voted but it is telling that, Once you earn a total of 15 reputation your vote will  change the publicly displayed post score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the connectedservice thread code is causing the issue. Instead of continuously racing grtBPM method, why don't you post the message only when there is a change. You can use local broadcast manager to broadcast the message from service and catch that in activity and update UI accordingly.  The connectedservice thread runs continuously and keep posting the message to handler which is causing load on the main thread.